# Java - XML Generation - Empty File

Tags: java, xml, file, io

I have a Java webservice that is triggered to perform integrations via XML file exchange with an ERP, it has worked perfectly since the day I developed it. Yesterday morning, he started to generate empty XML files without any changes to his source code. Any request made to it generates empty files, making the interface between the platforms impossible.
By analyzing the server log, the following error appears

```
ERROR:  'Input/output error'
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Input/output error
java.io.IOException: Input/output error
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:743)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:345)
        at br.com.allis.XMLFiles.RequisicaoReembolso.createXML(RequisicaoReembolso.java:252)
        at br.com.allis.XMLFiles.XMLParser.generateXML(XMLParser.java:63)
        at br.com.allis.ws.AllisWS.generateXML(AllisWS.java:1126)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:121)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:114)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:221)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:76)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:934)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1015)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:646)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1576)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1534)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Input/output error
java.io.IOException: Input/output error
        at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToStream.flushWriter(ToStream.java:304)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToXMLStream.endDocument(ToXMLStream.java:213)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToUnknownStream.endDocument(ToUnknownStream.java:829)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:139)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:98)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transformIdentity(TransformerImpl.java:687)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:731)
        ... 38 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Input/output error
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:345)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.WriterToUTF8Buffered.flushBuffer(WriterToUTF8Buffered.java:450)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.WriterToUTF8Buffered.flush(WriterToUTF8Buffered.java:469)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToStream.flushWriter(ToStream.java:285)
        ... 44 more
```

I already tried to redeploy it, since there was no change of its code but without success.
When I run the application locally, it works normally...

```java
public ReturnMsg createXML(String paramsJson) {
        ReturnMsg retorno = new ReturnMsg();
        try {
            JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
            DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
            Element root = doc.createElement("DEMANDA");
            doc.appendChild(root);
            JsonObject requisicao = parser.parse(paramsJson).getAsJsonObject();
            String numDemanda = requisicao.get("NUM_DEM").getAsString();
            int numRequisicao = Integer.parseInt(numDemanda);
            this.log.setNumeroDemanda(numRequisicao);
            String tpDemanda = requisicao.get("TIP_DEM").getAsString();
            String codEmpresa = requisicao.get("COD_EMP").getAsString();
            String cnpj = requisicao.get("CNPJ_FOR").getAsString();
            String cpf = requisicao.get("CPF_FOR").getAsString();
            String dtFaturamento = requisicao.get("DAT_FAT").getAsString();
            String textExp = requisicao.get("TEX_EXP").getAsString();
            String textCab = requisicao.get("TEX_CAB").getAsString();
            String destRecurso = requisicao.get("DEST_REC").getAsString();
            String motivoDespesa = requisicao.get("MOT_DESP").getAsString()
            int numDestRecurso = Integer.parseInt(destRecurso);
            int numMotivoDespesa = motivoDespesa != "" ? Integer.parseInt(motivoDespesa) : 0;

            Element src = doc.createElement("SRC");
            String txtSrc = "fluig";

            Element nDemanda = doc.createElement("NUM_DEM");
            Element tDemanda = doc.createElement("TIP_DEM");
            Element cEmpresa = doc.createElement("COD_EMP");
            Element cnpjF = doc.createElement("CNPJ_FOR");
            Element cpfF = doc.createElement("CPF_FOR");
            Element dtFat = doc.createElement("DAT_FAT");
            Element txtExp = doc.createElement("TEX_EXP");
            Element txtCab = doc.createElement("TEX_CAB");
            Element itens = doc.createElement("ITENS");

            src.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(txtSrc));
            nDemanda.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(numDemanda));
            tDemanda.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(tpDemanda));
            cEmpresa.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(codEmpresa));
            cnpjF.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(cnpj));
            cpfF.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(cpf));
            dtFat.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(dtFaturamento));
            txtExp.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(textExp));
            txtCab.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(textCab));

            root.appendChild(src);
            root.appendChild(nDemanda);
            root.appendChild(tDemanda);
            root.appendChild(cEmpresa);
            root.appendChild(cnpjF);
            root.appendChild(cpfF);
            root.appendChild(dtFat);
            root.appendChild(txtExp);
            root.appendChild(txtCab);

            JsonArray itensJson = requisicao.get("ITENS").getAsJsonArray();

            for (int i = 0, size = itensJson.size(); i < size; i++) {
                JsonObject obj = (JsonObject) itensJson.get(i);

                Element item = doc.createElement("ITEM");
                Element tipDes = doc.createElement("TIP_DES");
                Element valLin = doc.createElement("VAL_LIN");
                Element cCusto = doc.createElement("C_CUSTO");
                Element ePep = doc.createElement("E_PEP");

                if( i == 0 ){
                    String cenCusto = !obj.get("C_CUSTO").getAsString().isEmpty() ? obj.get("C_CUSTO").getAsString() : obj.get("E_PEP").getAsString();
                }
                item.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(obj.get("ITEM").getAsString()));
                tipDes.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(obj.get("TIP_DES").getAsString()));
                valLin.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(obj.get("VAL_LIN").getAsString()));
                cCusto.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(obj.get("C_CUSTO").getAsString()));
                ePep.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(obj.get("E_PEP").getAsString()));


                item.appendChild(tipDes);
                item.appendChild(valLin);
                item.appendChild(cCusto);
                item.appendChild(ePep);

                itens.appendChild(item);
            }


            root.appendChild(itens);

            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);

            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION,"yes");
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD,"xml");

            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(this.getNomeArq()));
            transformer.transform(source, result); // error triggers here

            retorno.setSuccess(true);
            retorno.setMotivo("Sucesso");
            retorno.setObs("Arquivo gerado com sucesso");
            retorno.setTipoRetorno("ok");
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
            pce.printStackTrace();
            retorno.setSuccess(false);
            retorno.setMotivo("Erro");
            retorno.setObs("Erro criação do arquivo XML");
            retorno.setTipoRetorno("exc");
        } catch (TransformerException te) {
            te.printStackTrace();
            retorno.setSuccess(false);
            retorno.setMotivo("Erro");
            retorno.setObs("Erro criação do arquivo XML");
            retorno.setTipoRetorno("exc");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            retorno.setSuccess(false);
            retorno.setMotivo("Erro");
            retorno.setObs("Erro criação do arquivo XML");
            retorno.setTipoRetorno("exc");
        }
        return retorno;
    }
```

Expected output should be a XML file with this structure

```xml
<DEMANDA>
    <SRC></SRC>
    <NUM_DEM></NUM_DEM>
    <TIP_DEM></TIP_DEM>
    <COD_EMP></COD_EMP>
    <CNPJ_FOR></CNPJ_FOR>
    <CPF_FOR></CPF_FOR>
    <DAT_FAT></DAT_FAT>
    <TEX_EXP></TEX_EXP>
    <TEX_CAB></TEX_CAB>
    <ITENS>
        <ITEM>
            <TIP_DES></TIP_DES>
            <VAL_LIN></VAL_LIN>
            <C_CUSTO></C_CUSTO>
            <E_PEP></E_PEP>
        </ITEM>
    </ITENS>
</DEMANDA>
```

Comment: Is that all the error on logs? Check disk space available and tmp directory permissions on the server.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz I've just pasted all the stacktrace... About disk space, double checked, there is plenty space